# Issue with Gmail not displaying old messages, including in "All Mail"

Tags: gmail

Interesting issue with Gmail that I'm seeing.

So, a friend asked me to look into why she can't see old emails, and she's had this problem for 6 months. She's telling me that it happened the day after she upgraded to Windows 10. My first thought was that it was an issue with not giving the Calendar/Mail app proper privileges, but I've confirmed myself this is not the case. I have checked and it should be syncing and displaying mail from "Any Time" and the emails come in "as they're received" (these are settings within the Mail app within Windows 10).

That's when I logged into Gmail, and find that within Gmail itself, even in the "All Mail" folder, only has around 250 emails total, well under the 3000 emails that were expected to be there. I also searched with "in:anywhere" to see if additional mail would appear, but only the small subset of 250 emails appeared.

What is interesting is that still 1.49 GB of space is being taken, even though we can't see the emails. My hope is that the emails still may be there, just not displayed for whatever reason.

Has anyone else run into a problem like this?

I don't BELIEVE her account has been compromised in any way, but that's the only conclusion I can come to at this point, but I don't wan't to rule anything else out.

Comment: Did you check "Trash" to see if they were deleted recently? If "All Mail" is only showing 250 messages, that's all there is.

Comment: Yes, I checked Trash, and Spam, only the expected messages were there (not the last 2750 messages we were hoping to see)

Comment: Bear in mind that the Gmail/Drive storage space meter could take up 24 hours to update. How does the Mail app within Windows 10 connect to the Gmail account? Does it use POP and it's settings are set to leave messages in the server? Are there more devices connected to the account? Are there third party apps connected?

Comment: I would suspect the mail app has probably removed those old messages.

Comment: Does she use any mail app for that account on a mobile device?

Comment: Ruben - it is set to use IMAP, not POP.

Comment: She does access her mail using her iPhone as well btw

Comment: Have had the exact same issue myself. Luckily I remembered some keywords in the emails I was looking for and was able to find via the search function. I have filed them in a separate folder as well. If I search they are there. Interesting thing is, if I move a new email to the folder the oldest mail in the folder disappears and can only be found using the search function?? Back to Hotmail I guess!

Comment: I've experienced exactly the same. One day I searched for an email from 2010, which came up during the search, and only then did it stay in my inbox. Again I search for something old from 2012, which again came up and then also displayed in my inbox. So at the moment I have email from current up to 07/2017 and underneath it, the two emails above. So if you don't ask for it you won't see it....